# Why does the div named boxes is above the footer? And why may the footer have all that extra white space below it?

Tags: html, css

What I mean in relation to the div with the class boxes is that it was supposed to be the container for box1 and box2 but it is down there, just above the footer.
Also it would be helpful to tell me if you think that I could have done determine things better/more effectively (e.g. there was no need for certain divs, another method would have been better to position elements, the code could be cleaner, etc.)
Thank you very much.

HTML code (without the head and header copied here for simplicity):

```
<body>
  
    <main>
        <section class="introduction">
            <div class="container-intro">
        <h1 class="header1">The Future Is Here</h1>
            </div>
                <div class="boxes"> 
                    <div class="box1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></div>
                    <div class="box2"><a href="#">Sign In</a></div>
                </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
       <ul class="smedia-icons">
        <li><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></li>
       </ul>

    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
   *{
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
}

main{
background: linear-gradient(#ff416c, #ff4b2b);
margin-top: 0px;
}
.header1{
text-align: center;
padding: 270px;
color: white;
font-size: 90px;
}
footer{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.smedia-icons li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative; top: 950px;
  
}
.boxes{
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 font-size: medium;
 font-weight: bolder;

}

.box1{
  height: 30px ;
  width: 150px ;
  padding: 10px ;
  border: ;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; top: -200px; left: 200px;

}
.box2{
  height: 30px ;
  width: 150px ;
  padding: 10px ;
  border: ;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; top: -200px; left: -200px;

}
.box1:hover, .box2:hover{
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

Comment: I don't see white space under the `footer`. The `div` with the `class boxes` is above the `footer` because it is above the `footer` in the HTML markup? See https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/NWNYNoj

Comment: What i mean is that the div boxes was supposed to be the container for box1 and box2, but instead is down there. Also in the footer i don't see the social media icons. And in relation to the white space, in your link it isn' there but when I open the file in Chrome or Safari, it is there.

Comment: Ah ok, well it,s because .boxes does not have any height or width defined so it looks like that but box1 and box2 are entirely inside .boxes yes.

Comment: So is .boxes ok down there, or should I change it? Also, question about your link: Why does the page have a different font and the social media icons don't appear? If you know what's wrong with the white space below the footer (that appears in chrome and safari), help would be appreciated

Comment: See my answer, nothing wrong with boxes. Your icons were not displaying b/c inside the <li> tags not sure why. So I used a flexbox layout instead it seems to look good.

Comment: Do you expect the footer to be above the main part of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Codepen: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/NWNYNoj

The only edits to your code were removing the `<li></li>` tags and using a flex display inside the .smediaicons div with a left and right margins of 15px for the social media icons. I also used a font-size of 45px.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <main>
    <section class="introduction">
      <div class="container-intro">
        <h1 class="header1">The Future Is Here</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box1">
          <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box2">
          <a href="#">Sign In</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="smedia-icons">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
      </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
  *{
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
}

main{
background: linear-gradient(#ff416c, #ff4b2b);
margin-top: 0px;
}

.smedia-icons {
  display:flex;justify-content:center;
}
.header1{
text-align: center;
padding: 270px;
color: white;
font-size: 90px;
}
footer{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.smedia-icons i{
font-size:45px;
  margin:0 15px;
 
}
.boxes{
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 font-size: medium;
 font-weight: bolder;

}

.box1{
  height: 30px ;
  width: 150px ;
  padding: 10px ;
  border: ;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; top: -200px; left: 200px;

}
.box2{
  height: 30px ;
  width: 150px ;
  padding: 10px ;
  border: ;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; top: -200px; left: -200px;

}
.box1:hover, .box2:hover{
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Two things: the social media icons have bullet points next to them (when I open it in chrome or safari), which I tried to remove with list-style: none; but still aren't being able to remove, and the second thing is: what change that you made do you think that solve the problem with the extra space below the footer? Also when I use the chrome inspect element and hover over the s media icons, in the code they still appear as <li> in a <ul>, why can it be?

Comment: It's not possible because I removed the ul and li tags entirely. You must be loading an old cached version or something like that. On the codepen, there is no bullet point? Let me know. For the footer, it is positioned at the very bottom by default when you use the "footer" tag (you were using id="footer").

Comment: Thank you! That thing about the white space below the footer was strange, my code in the question that I uploaded didn't have the id footer, it had the footer tag, so don't now what the problem. Also, when I open the file in chrome the footer is fine, but when I inspect the page the white space below the footer is still there for several screen sizes, mostly from 1300 x 1165 upwards.

Comment: I can't reproduce that white space at any window width, sorry.